# not resolving item for playframework zipWithIndex function

Tags: scala, playframework

I have the following code snippet:

```
for((item, index) <- userModelList.zipWithIndex){
<tr>
    <td> @counter </td>
    <td> @item.modelName </td>
</tr>
@(counter = counter + 1)
}
```

I have also included at the top of my file.scala.html:

```
@(userModelList:List[models.UserModel], message: String)
```

The compile throws an error saying that "item" is not being found. I have used this syntax in the past and it worked just fine. Currently, I am using Play 2.6 and Scala Version 2.12.4. Thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: Where's @counter coming from? Where is it declared? Is this the exact code? (`for` is missing the `@`)

Comment: @AlvaroCarrasco yeah, after staring at the screen for 10 minutes I realized that I had missed the @ symbol before for to consider it as a dynamic statement. That was so stupid of me. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with the above code snippet was missing the

> @ symbol before the for statement

provided that the variable counter was correctly declared.